# use value from a col to choose value from another col, put into new df in R

Tags: r

I have a df like this

```
name <- c("Fred","Mark","Jen","Simon","Ed")
a_or_b <- c("a","a","b","a","b")
abc_ah_one <- c(3,5,2,4,7)
abc_bh_one <- c(5,4,1,9,8)
abc_ah_two <- c(2,1,3,7,6)
abc_bh_two <- c(3,6,8,8,5)
abc_ah_three <- c(5,4,7,6,2)
abc_bh_three <- c(9,7,2,1,4)
def_ah_one <- c(1,3,9,2,7)
def_bh_one <- c(2,8,4,6,1)
def_ah_two <- c(4,7,3,2,5)
def_bh_two <- c(5,2,9,8,3)
def_ah_three <- c(8,5,3,5,2)
def_bh_three <- c(2,7,4,3,0)
df <- data.frame(name,a_or_b,abc_ah_one,abc_bh_one,abc_ah_two,abc_bh_two,
abc_ah_three,abc_bh_three,def_ah_one,def_bh_one,
def_ah_two,def_bh_two,def_ah_three,def_bh_three)
```

I want to use the value in column "a_or_b" to choose the values in each of the corresponding "ah/bh" columns for each "abc" (one, two, and three), and put it into a new data frame. For example, Fred would have the values 3, 2 and 5 in his row in the new df. Those values represent the values of each of his "ah" categories for the abc columns. Jen, who has "b" in her a_or_b column, would have all of her "bh" values from her abc columns for her row in the new df. Here is what my desired output would look like:

```
combo_one <- c(3,5,1,4,8)
combo_two <- c(2,1,8,7,5)
combo_three <- c(5,4,2,6,4)
df2 <- data.frame(name,a_or_b,combo_one,combo_two,combo_three)
```

I've attempted this using sapply. The following gives me a matrix of the correct column correct indexes of `df[grep("abc",colnames(df),fixed=TRUE)]` for each row:

```
sapply(paste0(df$a_or_b,"h"),grep,colnames(df[grep("abc",colnames(df),fixed=TRUE)]))
```

Comment: So the `def` columns are ignored?

Comment: Yes, def columns are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we gather your data into a tidy long format, then break out the columns into something useful. After that the filtering is simple, and if necessary we can convert back to an difficult wide format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(df, key = "var", value = "val", -name, -a_or_b) %>%
  separate(var, into = c("combo", "h", "ind"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(h = substr(h, 1, 1)) %>%
  filter(a_or_b == h, combo == "abc") %>%
  arrange(name) -> result_long
result_long
#     name a_or_b combo h   ind val
# 1     Ed      b   abc b   one   8
# 2     Ed      b   abc b   two   5
# 3     Ed      b   abc b three   4
# 4   Fred      a   abc a   one   3
# 5   Fred      a   abc a   two   2
# 6   Fred      a   abc a three   5
# 7    Jen      b   abc b   one   1
# 8    Jen      b   abc b   two   8
# 9    Jen      b   abc b three   2
# 10  Mark      a   abc a   one   5
# 11  Mark      a   abc a   two   1
# 12  Mark      a   abc a three   4
# 13 Simon      a   abc a   one   4
# 14 Simon      a   abc a   two   7
# 15 Simon      a   abc a three   6

spread(result_long, key = ind, value = val) %>%
  select(name, a_or_b, one, two, three)
#    name a_or_b one two three
# 1    Ed      b   8   5     4
# 2  Fred      a   3   2     5
# 3   Jen      b   1   8     2
# 4  Mark      a   5   1     4
# 5 Simon      a   4   7     6
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R approach would be using `lapply`, we loop through each row of the dataframe, create a string to find similar columns using `paste0` based on `a_or_b` column and then `rbind` all the values together for each row.

```
new_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x) 
 setNames(df[x, grepl(paste0("abc_",df[x,"a_or_b"], "h"), colnames(df))], 
                           c("combo_one", "combo_two", "combo_three"))))

new_df
#  combo_one combo_two combo_three
#1         3         2           5
#2         5         1           4
#3         1         8           2
#4         4         7           6
#5         8         5           4
```

We can `cbind` the required columns then :

```
cbind(df[c(1, 2)], new_df)

#   name a_or_b combo_one combo_two combo_three
#1  Fred      a         3         2           5
#2  Mark      a         5         1           4
#3   Jen      b         1         8           2
#4 Simon      a         4         7           6
#5    Ed      b         8         5           4
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with a combination of `map` and `mutate`:

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(name, a_or_b, starts_with("abc")) %>%
  rename_if(is.numeric, funs(sub("abc_", "", .))) %>%
  mutate(combo_one = map_chr(a_or_b, ~ paste0(.x,"h_one")),
         combo_one = !!combo_one,
         combo_two = map_chr(a_or_b, ~ paste0(.x,"h_two")),
         combo_two = !!combo_two,
         combo_three = map_chr(a_or_b, ~ paste0(.x,"h_three")),
         combo_three = !!combo_three) %>%
  select(name, a_or_b, starts_with("combo"))
```

Output:

```
   name a_or_b combo_one combo_two combo_three
1  Fred      a         3         2           5
2  Mark      a         5         1           4
3   Jen      b         1         8           2
4 Simon      a         4         7           6
5    Ed      b         8         5           4
```